# file_get_contents fails if it see 404

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have an array containing URLs. I'm trying to get the contents one by one, but sometimes, when a URL is a 404, the `file_get_contents()` fails.

```
function pageContent(String $url): \DOMDocument
    {
       $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {

           $opts = [
               "http" => [
                   "method" => "GET",
                   "header" => "Accept: text/html\r\n"
               ]
           ];

           try {

               $context = stream_context_create($opts);
               $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

               return $file;

           } catch (\Exception $e) {

           }

       });
       $parser = new \DOMDocument();
       libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

       $parser->loadHTML($html = mb_convert_encoding($html,'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ASCII, JIS, UTF-8, EUC-JP, SJIS'));

       return $parser;
    }
```

I tried try catch on it but getting this error. This time loadHTML fails.

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input
```

Comment: do NOT use `file_get_contents()` for networking. Use `cURL` instead.

Comment: It's pretty obvious in the code that if you are falling into the "catch" statement, the catch isn't returning anything, thus the `$html` variable is empty. And there you have it, it's complaining about having an empty $html.

Comment: If you don't want that to complain about an empty string, well, check the value of $html before passing it to DOMDocument::loadHTML();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the `$html` is empty before loading it via `loadHTML()`:

```
if(!is_empty($html)) {
    $parser->loadHTML($html = mb_convert_encoding($html,'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ASCII, JIS, UTF-8, EUC-JP, SJIS'));
} else {
    return null;
}
```